# How to check if letters of one string are in another

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list L of words in alphabetical order, e.g hello = ehllo
how do I check for this words "blanagrams", which are words with mostly all similar letters except 1. For example, orchestra turns into orchestre. I've only been able to think to this part. I have an idea in which you have to test every letter of the current word and see whether this corresponds, to the other and if it does, it is a blanagram and create a dictionary, but i'm struggling to put it into code

```
L = [list of alphabetically ordered strings]

for word in L:

     for letter in word:
        #confused at this part
```

Comment: A better idea would be to use structures\objects that do not undestand order such as `sets` to check your expression. Checking for the intersection of `set(hello)` and `set(ehllo)` is easier than trying to reassemble the letters to get from one word to the other. But `sets` do not allow duplicate entriesl, so be careful..

Comment: First, you need two words to compare, but your code has only one, so far.  Also, you don't need to check every word, words of different lengths automatically fail, correct? Then, you only need to compare two words until you find two letters that don't match.

Comment: Is this part of the ladders game commonly used in AI ?
Are you trying to create a graph with adjacent nodes as possible words and not a dictionary ? Elaborate your question.

Comment: I'll add a compare len I guess so. My list is pretty extensive, with around 2 million words, but didn't put here obviously. 

My main problem is how to compare 2 specific words using the code I have so far, all I can think of is
     if len(word[0]) == len(word[1])

do you know a method to compare 2 words?

Comment: `'hello'` and `'hella'` differ by 1.  What do `'hello'` and `'heela'` differ by?  In other words, do letter counts matter or do only letters used matter?  One more example `'tttah'` vs `'ttaax'`.

Comment: only one letter is allowed to be changed in a blanagram at a time. So only hella would be valid, whereas heela would not.

Comment: What about letter ordering? Is "hello" the same as "leloh"?

Comment: that doesn't matter, at long as the word is present in a list of words I was provided with (pretty much a valid real word), then I will create a new dictionary in which the orderd version of hello, "ehllo" = ["hello", "another string which has the same bar 1 letter", "..."] etc

Comment: Are you making this for a scrabble type game where you need to figure out how to use a blank?

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
def same_except1(s1, s2):
    ct1, ct2 = Counter(s1), Counter(s2)
    return sum((ct1 - ct2).values()) == 1 and sum((ct2 - ct1).values()) == 1
```

Examples:

```
>>> same_except1('hello', 'hella')
True
>>> same_except1('hello', 'heela')
False
>>> same_except1('hello', 'hello')
False
>>> same_except1('hello', 'helloa')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Steven Rumbalski's answer got me thinking and there's also another way you can do this with a Counter (+1 for use of collections and thank you for sparking my interest)

```
from collections import Counter
def diff_one(w,z):
    c=Counter(sorted(w+z)).values()
    c=filter(lambda x:x%2!=0,c)
    return len(c)==2
```

Basically all matched letters will have a counter value that will be even. So you filter those out and get left with the unmatched ones. If you have more than 2 unmatched then you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is similar to the  part of the ladders game commonly used in AI, and you are trying to create a graph with adjacent nodes as possible words and not a dictionary.

```
d = {}
# create buckets of words that differ by one letter
for word in L:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        bucket = word[:i] + '_' + word[i+1:]
        if bucket in d:
            d[bucket].append(word)
        else:
            d[bucket] = [word]
```

Comment: currently, I have a dictionary named N, of anagrams of words, such as
 
"'acehorrst" = ["orchestra", "carthorse"] what I'm thinking of doing, is comparing the dictionary key, which is "acehorsst" against other keys in my dictionary. If all of the letter except one are the same, then create a new dictionary, where "acehorsst" would be the key, and the word which is the same except one character, be the value, and there may be more than one of these words. The problem is, i'm struggling to do this anyway.

Comment: with my list of around 2.5million words this takes extremely long. I have a program which finds anagrams already. In which I explained the "acehorrst" = ["orchestra", "carthorse"] so I was thinking of making a function (e.g blanagram(word, anagram), where anagram is the dictionary for anagrams like "acehorrst" = ["orchestra", "carthorse"]  for 2.5 million words, and word is the user's input. therefore, I was thinking of doing "for letter in word" then replace each letter with a new letter to see which words can be formed.

Comment: Then create a new dictionary of the original word = ["words with one letter different"], but i'm struggling how to implement this into code (swapping out each letter with a new one and testing if the original word with a letter changed is a word in my list of words of 2.5 million